# In my Heroku production App I can't Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, sendgrid

I can login in as the Admin on my local web app but when I got to Heroku to login it says I need to confirm the email that was sent to my inbox. The problem is I don't ever get the email sent to my inbox when I ask it to resend.

So right now I can't login.

Here is a link to my Heroku app
https://chip-reddit.herokuapp.com

Here is a link to my github. 
https://github.com/goldmullet/bloccit

Any idea why?

Comment: Contact SendGrid support, I also suspect that this is spam. You should know that a free SendGrid account made through SendGrid has more features than the one you get through heroku.

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be with the mail provider. In my experience SendGrid regularly need contacting via their web site support to manually intervene to allow Heroku apps to send email. I believe this is an anti-spam measure.

As a temporary workaround (perhaps while waiting for SendGrid to respond), you can manually confirm your user through the rails console. In the terminal:

```
heroku run rails c

# ...
# Wait a few seconds for rails console to open
# ...

# Get admin user out of the db and mark as confirmed
admin = User.find_by(email: "your-admin-email@goes.here")
admin.skip_confirmation!
admin.save!

# Exit the console
exit
```